# Rotate orthographic camera (shadow camera) in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to rotate a shadow camera by 45 degrees. I've managed to rotate the directional light it's attached to using the following code:

```
sunlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
sunlight.position.x = -camera.position.x ;
sunlight.position.y = 300;
sunlight.position.z = camera.position.z ; //default; light shining from top

var vector = new THREE.Vector3;
vector.subVectors(scene.position, sunlight.position);
var q = new THREE.Quaternion();
q.setFromAxisAngle( vector.normalize(), Math.PI / 4 );
sunlight.applyQuaternion( q );
```

However the shadow camera does not rotate with the light as I'd expected. Trying to rotate the shadow camera itself using the same code does not work. How do I rotate an orthographic camera around its center point?

In the attached image the shadow camera can be seen as the orange square. The light is the black square, seen rotated 45 degrees. I need to apply the same rotation to the orange square as well, so the blue arrow is pointing north west.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Directional lights in THREE.js don't behave like you'd expect. There is a light.target Vector3 parameter that the light Always points to.. so changing the lights rotation won't really do much. Try changing light.target to aim the light. To affect the roll of the shadow camera, you may be able to set the order of its euler with camera.rotation.order = "ZYX". Let me know if this helps.

@Joe Morgan

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changing the camera rotation order still hasn't worked. The thing is I don't want to change what the light it pointing at. I want it to be pointing at the center of the scene, I just need it to be rotated to the same angle as the grid, and the light itself is coming from the south west @manthrax

Comment: Have you tried all the different combinations of rotation order.. "XYZ", "ZYX", "YZX", etc? The problem here is that the default behavior of directional lights, is to rotate to point toward the target. This overrides whatever rotation/quaternion you set yourself. You can try disabling that behavior by doing light.matrixAutoUpdate = false; but then when you change the rotation manually, you may have to call light.updateMatrix() and/or light.updateMatrixWorld().. try some of these approaches and see how that goes? @Joe Morgan